# CURL / screen scrape delivery tracking details from Canada Post

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I need to obtain delivery tracking details from the Canada Post website, which does not offer an API.

I've formulated a URL that when entered into a browser correctly returns the tracking information, but I can't get the request to function with CURL (it returns a 500 We're Sorry page).

```
class cURL { 
var $headers; 
var $user_agent; 
var $compression; 
var $cookie_file; 
var $proxy; 
function cURL($cookies=TRUE,$cookie='cookies.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy='') { 
$this->headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg'; 
$this->headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive'; 
$this->headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'; 
$this->user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)'; 
$this->compression=$compression; 
$this->proxy=$proxy; 
$this->cookies=$cookies; 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie); 
} 
function cookie($cookie_file) { 
if (file_exists($cookie_file)) { 
$this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
} else { 
fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions'); 
$this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
fclose($this->cookie_file); 
} 
} 
function get($url) { 
$process = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); 
curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($cUrl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'proxy_ip:proxy_port'); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
$return = curl_exec($process); 
curl_close($process); 
return $return; 
} 
function post($url,$data) { 
$process = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file); 
if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$return = curl_exec($process); 
curl_close($process); 
return $return; 
} 
function error($error) { 
echo "cURL Error
$error"; 
die; 
} 
} 
$cc = new cURL(); 
$test = $cc->get('http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?trackingNumber=x0x0x0x0x0x0x0&trackingType=trackPersonal'); 

echo $test;
```

**[UPDATE]** after removing the Accept header line as per Tim's reply, I now get a page with the following 'You are currently visiting our Basic Site. This site is used for low-bandwidth connections, mobile devices and alternative browsers.' - but, again, no tracking information.

Comment: I had to write a shopping cart to deal with CanadaPost (for shipping rate calculation) two weeks ago... I feel your pain man. Even their *dedicated API* for rate calculation is janky. I can't imagine what scraping from them is like... Eeek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with this line:

```
$this->headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
```

Add `text/html` and you should be good. Or just drop that header.

Comment: Thank you. I've removed that line and now get a page with following text 'You are currently visiting our Basic Site. This site is used for low-bandwidth connections, mobile devices and alternative browsers.' - again this does not display the tracking information. I'm guessing it might be to do with the user agent being sent?

Comment: It looks like the URL you're using is redirected - perhaps it's not a header redirect, but a JS or Meta based redirect. Just a guess

Comment: I take it that if that is the case there's nothing I can do to get around the issue?

Comment: From a quick look, it seems like the page you send get vars takes the data and POSTs it someplace. I'd take a look at the tracking form at the bottom of the 'mobile' page you get now (using CURL).

Comment: Well, low and behold, it now seems to be working great :) I'm honestly not sure what changed, but I now have the tracking info in the returned page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used **[Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/)** for screen scrapes.
Totally recommended.

**UPDATE:**
I could fetch that content using Snoopy (but I needed to modify a simple line: 809)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include('Snoopy.class.php');

    $http = new Snoopy();
    $http->fetch('http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?trackingNumber=x0x0x0x0x0x0x0&trackingType=trackPersonal');

    echo $http->results;
?>
```

You need to download Snoopy library and modify the line 809:

```
$cookie_headers .= $cookieKey."=".urlencode($cookieVal)."; ";
```

with:

```
$cookie_headers .= $cookieKey."=".$cookieVal."; ";
```

And voilà!

Comment: The SF site doesn't seem to have much info - care to elaborate on what it provides?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I've upvoted, but in this instance I think snoopy is a bit heavyweight for my application.

Answer (score 1):

How old is this thread? Canadapost certainly does offer an API.
http://sellonline.canadapost.ca/DevelopersResources/